# Apache2 unexcepted behavior log file

Tags: python, logging, flask, apache2, wsgi

Since today, error log from apache stop writting in the path i've given, instead it goes back in the default logging file.

I the apache2 vhost config, i've set the ErrorLog to a value

${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ghost_error.log ,

but when there is error to log, it's write in the

${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

We are using Flask with apache2.

There is the config file for apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
[...]
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ghost/ghost.wsgi

[...]

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ghost_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ghost_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And there is the wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
  ghost_path='/home/www'
  chdir_this = '%s/ghost/' % ghost_path
  activate_this = '%s/ghost_env/bin/activate_this.py' % ghost_path
  import os
  os.chdir(chdir_this)
  execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

  reload(os)
  import sys
  import logging

  os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/App/"))
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/App/"))
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  from App import app as application
except Exception, e:
  import traceback
  with open('/tmp/ghost.fail.log', 'w') as f:
    f.write("%s\n%s" % (e, traceback.format_exc()))
```

We simply have no idea of where it can come from.
If you do have some hint to follow !

Thanks.

Comment: If on a Linux system which uses a ``sites-available`` directory, make sure the reference in ``sites-enabled`` is actually a symlink to the file in ``sites-available`` and that someone has turned it into a real file and changed it. The other possibility is that your ``VirtualHost`` is no longer matching and it is falling back to the first default ``VirtualHost`` although that would require that their still be a mapping for the WSGI application in play somehow.

Comment: After few restart of the apache2 server it has been writting in the right file again.
It was a weird story, and in my sites-enabled, it's well a symlink to the sites-avaible's file.